# SaveIntoDatabase: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android

Tengo un porblema a la hora de cargar mi base de datos SQlite con un array en segundo plano, el problema es el siguiente:

```
 SaveIntoDatabase: Can't create handler inside thread that has not
 called Looper.prepare()
```

Estuve investigando sobre looper para entender su funcionamiento, intente llamar a Looper.prepare dentro del void run(), pero no hubo diferencia

Aqui el codigo

```
public class ProductFetcher extends Thread {

    private final ProductFetchListener mListener;
    private final SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public ProductFetcher(ProductFetchListener listener, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mListener = listener;
        mDb = db;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(Constants.DATABASE.GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY, null);

        final List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Product product = new Product();
                    product.setFromDatabase(true);

                   Aqui cargo los campos del producto  

                    productList.add(product);
                    publishProduct(product);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mListener.onDeliverAllProducts(productList);
                mListener.onHideDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    public void publishProduct(final Product product) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mListener.onDeliverProduct(product);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Intente tambien colocar el Looper.prepare() dentro de todos los public void run(), y el resultado era que no podia llamar a mas de uno por thread

Answer (score 0):

después de crear el Handler agrega el `Looper.prepare()`, este debe quedar antes del post